# The parented object to my Armature disappears when a starting animation in BGE

Tags: animation, armature, game-engine, parent, actions

Version: Blender Game Gngine 2.7.9

The object always has an `idle animation` action playing and it works perfectly and it doesn't disappear when I get close to it.

But when I shoot the object, The death animation starts and when I get close to the object, the object starts to disappear when I get close to it.

Here is a [GIF](https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEin2bxbNwDrFl47DJDGNmEG6hraa8BHV6GDGppdfAxxsFjPeII25w5RJs0lvGqIK6Pn-5HjVsg9D7hHZGCwUaQQWu91iWKFUo23T21FLA0bC_EnJCOqCROlSPymKRPK6MNwaHmnWtqpKgw5XwZ5WvNwqWRHj9ME_fJfc_mzPoYN7fp4vXjOaFwpZiH0=s16000) to help better understand the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like your animations have conflicting transforms values. Have you considered using Action layers to separate the transform values individually.

Comment: They are.
I noticed that the problem has something to do with the player cam, I got another one close to the object and it didn't disappear.

Comment: the player cam is connected to an empty that is connected to an armature and they are linked to a cube that has the character physics, If that is going to help, all player objects like models and cam are set to no collusion except the gun aim line is set to static actor

Comment: I found someone that is facing a similar problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IESuRHENml4